# Upload in array using verot class.upload.php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm using verot's class.upload.php to upload some images. [Class Link](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php)

Now I need to send some images in array. How to do using verot class.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s10">
    <div class="bg-branco">
      <input name="avariaNome[]" type="text" placeholder="Referencia">
      <input name="avariaFoto[]" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPLOAD**

```
if (!empty($_FILES['avariaFoto']['name'])) {
  $handle = new upload($_FILES['avariaFoto']);
  if ($handle - > uploaded) {
    $handle - > file_new_name_body = date('dmYhis');
    $handle - > image_resize = true;
    $handle - > image_x = 800;
    $handle - > image_ratio_y = true;
    $handle - > jpeg_quality = 80;
    $handle - > image_convert = 'jpg';
    $handle - > file_overwrite = false;
    $handle - > file_auto_rename = true;
    $handle - > mime_check = true;
    $handle - > Process('imagens/');
    $foto = $handle - > file_dst_name;

    if ($handle - > processed) {
      $handle - > clean();
    } else {
      echo '  Erro: '.$handle - > error.
      '';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s10">
    <div class="bg-branco">
      <input name="avariaNome[]" type="text" placeholder="Referencia">
      <input name="avariaFoto[]" type="file" multiple>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By PHP side you have an array as you will see through var_dump:

```
var_dump($_FILES['avariaFoto'])
```

Comment: Hi. I had this error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use []`